# Label and Text Input Box Mismatch in JAWS Cursor Mode

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

My application needs to be approved by an accessibility group.

I have a ASP.NET web forms application wherein in the JAWS cursor mode: after reading a label, under keydown press, the focus should move to the text input box.

Now the labl and textbox inputs are perfectly matched in HTML. So, no issues there.

Yet, JAWS reader upon keydown moves to the next label instead of the text input box.

I am very new to this accessibility thing:

1. I tried adding javascript such that when label is selected and keydown event happens, move to the textbox. It  has no effect on the cursor mode in JAWS.
2. I read somewhere there are aria attributes for this purpose? What aria attribute to use and where to help solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `aria-hidden='true'` on your `input`
good luck
shelli
Accessibility Expert